# Import XML to Dataset or read XML using XPath?

Tags: c#, xpath, dataset, xpathdocument

I'd like to know what is the best practice.
I'm exporting some data (tables) from my database to XML files so I can read my data from them.
To export, I'm using DataTable.WriteXml (c#)
Now to read, what is best? to import them into a dataset and use DataTable.Select to get the row I want or create an XPathDocument and use XPath to get the data? which performs best? I'm still learning xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not load the exported XML in using `DataTable.ReadXml(fileName)`?  If you exported your table data using `DataTable.WriteXml(file, XmlWriteMode.XmlSchema)`, then you can import it in to a new `DataTable` using [ReadXml(file)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0z9zxd.aspx).

From an example in MSDN:

```
myOldTable.WriteXml(fileName, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
newTable.ReadXml(fileName);
```

If that's the case, I don't see where you'd need XPath.  If I'm misunderstanding your question, please let me know and I'll update accordingly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good, bacause that's what I'm doing already, I just wanted to know if I should use xpath instead since I'm working with XML's. But if that's not the case, even better! Thanks for your help.